# Do I need to perform any corrections on Level-2 Landsat imagery?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, land-cover, land-classification, atmospheric-correction

My objective is to perform a land cover classification with multiple scenes over historical imagery (one year every decade).

Most of the imagery I have downloaded is level-2 imagery. From my understanding level-2 imagery is already atmospherically corrected. But since I am using multiple scenes, does that mean I still have to manually perform corrections even though it is a level-2 product? If so, what are all the types of correction that I need? Atmospheric, solar, geometric?

Edit: When I mosaic the images I get a huge visual difference, even though the images are only taken days apart and I have mosaicked them so their stretch hand display settings should be the same.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to do any further atmospheric correction with Landsat OLI/TIRS Level-2 data products as they are already corrected to surface reflectance. These data will be sufficient for time-series analysis as well as work involving multiple scenes. However, make sure any older imagery (i.e. earlier than Landsat 8 OLI/TIRS) is also corrected to surface reflectance if you plan on using that for your time-series analysis.

Here are more details from [USGS EROS](https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/science/usgs-eros-archive-landsat-archives-landsat-8-olitirs-level-2-data-products?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects):

> The U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) offers on-demand production of
>   Landsat 8 Operational Land Imager/Thermal Infrared Sensor (OLI/TIRS)
>   Surface Reflectance data through EarthExplorer. Surface Reflectance
>   products provide an estimate of the surface spectral reflectance as it
>   would be measured at ground level in the absence of atmospheric
>   scattering or absorption. The Surface Reflectance products are
>   generated at the Earth Resources Observation and Science (EROS) Center
>   at a 30-meter spatial resolution. The EROS Science Processing
>   Architecture (ESPA) on-demand interface corrects satellite images for
>   atmospheric effects to create Level-2 data products.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

When I mosaic the images I get a huge visual difference, even though the images are only taken days apart and I have mosaicked them so their stretch hand display settings should be the same. I originally thought would be fixed by correction (hence the question). How would I fix this issue?

Comment: It looks like your original question morphed into two parts. I would recommend opening a new question so that you can get the answer you need. It looks like you need to color balance the imagery.